# ItemCollectionMetrics is empty after successful transactWrite using DynamoDB.DocumentClient

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

I am executing a `transactWrite` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#transactWrite-property) instruction to DynamoDb and expecting to get back `ItemCollectionMetrics` (I am specifying `ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'SIZE'` in the request).

The object gets returned empty `{}` even though changes happened on the dynamo db tables.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

**Code**

```
const dynamoResponse = await dynamoDbDocumentClient.transactWrite({
        TransactItems: [
            {
                Put: {
                    TableName: ENV.BLAH_CONTENT_COUNT_MESSAGES_TABLE,
                    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
                        '#v' : 'v',
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
                        ':v' : blah.v
                    },
                    ConditionExpression: '(attribute_exists(blahId) AND #v<>:v) OR attribute_not_exists(blahId)',
                    Item: {...blahCountMessage}
                }
            },
            {
                Update: {
                    TableName: ENV.BLAH_CONTENT_COUNTS_TABLE,
                    Key: { id: blahContentCount.id },
                    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
                        '#v' : 'v',
                        '#count' : 'count',
                        '#contentId': 'contentId'
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
                        ':v' : 1,
                        ':count' : deleted ? -1: 1,
                        ':contentId': blahContentCount.contentId,
                        ':defaultNumber': 0
                    },
                    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(cognitoId)',
                    UpdateExpression: 'SET #contentId = :contentId, #count = if_not_exists(#count, :defaultNumber) + :count, #v = if_not_exists(#v, :defaultNumber) + :v',
                    ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure: 'ALL_OLD'
                }
            }
        ],
        ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'SIZE'
    }).promise();
```

**Outupt**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dynamoResponse.ItemCollectionMetrics)); // {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the `ReturnItemCollectionMetrics ` to "NONE" and share the output?

Comment: I get `undefined` if I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(dynamoResponse.ItemCollectionMetrics));`

Comment: Well.. this is just a guess but.. Try to remove the `await` `.promise`

Comment: well, not sure how would that work. the sdk is all base on promises, you need the promise and the wait for the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReturnItemCollectionMetrics:

"Information about item collections, if any, that were affected by the operation. ItemCollectionMetrics is only returned if the request asked for it. If the table does not have any local secondary indexes, this information is not returned in the response."

Per: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ItemCollectionMetrics.html

Could it be that this transaction is either not updating anything - or you don't have an LSI?

Also of note: The documentation says that transactions are disabled for 
"global tables", I'm not exactly sure if they mean a GSI... but I am not 
using a LSI which might be also why no ItemCollectionMetrics is ever 
returned in response to my transactions.

If you update your parameter object to include  `ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'TOTAL'` the response object should look like:

```
   [ { TableName: 'table_name',
       CapacityUnits: 8,
       WriteCapacityUnits: 8 } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! Think I missed the `LSI` part on the documentation. Looks like is that!