# Javascript Trasnact Write failing on increment item

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a transact write in DynamoDB. I can't seem to see the error and the error says "validationError, none" which isn't particualarly helpful. The `Put` for sure works but I am keeping here for completeness in the example

```js
    await dynamoDb.transactWrite({
      TransactItems: [
        {
          Put: {
            TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
            Item: {
              pk: compoundId,
              sk: interest,
              gsi1pk: "#INTEREST",
              interest: interest,
              id,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          Update: {
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":num": 1,
              ":initial": 0,
            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#tally": "tally",
            },
            Key: {
              PK: shop,
              SK: interest,
            },
            TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
            UpdateExpression:
              "SET #tally = if_not_exists(tally, :initial) + :num",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```

I'm fairly confident that this is doable per these similar solved questions here:

[ItemCollectionMetrics is empty after successful transactWrite using DynamoDB.DocumentClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590816/itemcollectionmetrics-is-empty-after-successful-transactwrite-using-dynamodb-doc)

[Increment the value if it exists, else add a new entry in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66308659/increment-the-value-if-it-exists-else-add-a-new-entry-in-dynamodb/66308829#66308829)

Comment: I should have just deleted the `ExpressionAttributeNames` and then it would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to have worked and the error was adding the `ExpressionAttributeNames`

```js
    await dynamoDb.transactWrite({
      TransactItems: [
        {
          Put: {
            TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
            Item: {
              pk: compoundId,
              sk: interest,
              gsi1pk: "#INTEREST",
              watching: watching,
              interest: interest,
              id,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          Update: {
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":num": 1,
              ":initial": 0,
            },
            Key: {
              pk: shop,
              sk: interest,
            },
            TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
            UpdateExpression:
              "SET tally = if_not_exists(tally, :initial) + :num",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```